# Complex mathematics for 32-bit micro-controller

Tags: floating-point, microcontroller

Can any one help me in calculating complex calculations on 32-bit micro-controller in software. I'm using luminary LM3S9D96 and need to calculate logs(at base 10) and power in floating numbers, such as (170)^0.75.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question and answer format works best when you show what you have attempted and what does not work about it. This gives people as sense of what you are doing or trying to do. I've edited the tags of your question somewhat to help target your audience better.

Answer (score 1):

This Cortex M3 chip is not well suited for that kind of math, since it has no floating point hardware support.  Your compiler toolchain will have library implementations of `log` and `pow`, which will work, but will take many many cycles.

If you really need more speed, you can probably convert your algorithms to use fixed point math.  Or table lookups can be used if you have lots of memory to spare and limited range of inputs.